# How to close SFTP session with Azure logic app after task is finished?

Tags: azure, sftp, scheduled-task, session

We have an Azure logic app that checks every five minutes for files on an external SFTP server. Sometimes the requests fail. The external party indicated that this might be because the SFTP sessions are closed only after two hours, while additional sessions are created every five minutes. The logic app only needs a few seconds to finish its tasks. How can we close the SFTP session to the external server directly after the logic app task has finished?